# I don't understand why the distance was calculated using the length if the dot product

Tags: vectors

I don't understand why the distance was calculated using the length if the dot product https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV9Rv.png

Comment: The dot product extracts the component of $c_{st}$ that is perpendicular to the plane. When computing the distance between a point and plane, the length of this perpendicular component is what you want to compute. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us write the initial relatioship under the form:

$$M=A+s\vec{U}+t\vec{V} \ \iff \ M-A=\vec{AM}=s\vec{U}+t\vec{V}\tag{1}$$

The cross product of the two basis vectors of the plane:

$\vec{W} \ := \ \vec{U} \ \times \ \vec{V} =\pmatrix{-1\\-2\\1/2} \ \times \ \pmatrix{-2\\1\\1/2}=\pmatrix{-3/2\\-1/2\\-5}$ is a normal vector to the plane ; it is normalized in a second step (division by its norm $\sqrt{110}/2$) giving $n_0$.

Taking the dot product of (1) with $n_0$ gives:

$$\vec{AM}.n_0$$

gives the desired distance, because taking the dot product of a vector $V$ with a unit vector $n_0$ is equivalent to obtain the projection of vector $V$ onto the axis defined by $n_0$.